# How to 'Extract by location' in QGIS 2.99.0?

Tags: qgis-processing, select-by-location, qgis-3

Once in the good old times of QGIS 2.14.17, there was an 'extract by location' algorithm:

[image]

In QGIS 2.99.0 neither searching for 'extract' nor for 'location' delivers such result:

[image]

[image]

(Oops, *NO* hit when searching for 'location' in a geospatial processing environment?!)

**Question: How to 'Extract by location' in QGIS 2.99.0?**

Comment: Perhaps it hasn't been ported to the new API yet [whereas others have](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis)? Just a guess ;)

Comment: Aahh... this might be an explanation, obviously they're planning something special to a subset of the processing algorithms (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/1e13d733c27e1998ccb730c38f5f49a66d865b63), so I am going to impatiently wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm that the latest QGIS 2.99 version now contains your beloved tool :)

[image: Toolbox]

Comment: that's going to make my bad weathered weekend worthwhile ;-)